# lightning-input Type Number which is not allowing to add the Decimal Value

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I have `lightning-input` field with type `number` Basically I'm collecting the No of hours in this field.

There is the probability by Adding the decimal Value like 1.5, 2.5

When I add this in the field I'm getting `Your entry isn't a valid increment.`

```
 <div>
        <h2>Live Input Number</h2>
        <lightning-input type="number" name="seven" 
        value={amount} onchange={handleAmountChange} 
        placeholder="type the number of items..." label="Enter a number"  ></lightning-input>
        <p>
            Number of Items: {amount}
        </p>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `step` is 1 (whole numbers only). To allow other values, specify a step, which is the multiple to use. For example, 0.25 allows entering quarter hours, 0.1 would allow 6 minute increments, etc.

Here's an [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/CRpeWRhHn/1/edit):

```
<template>
 <div>
        <h2>Live Input Number</h2>
        <lightning-input type="number" name="seven" 
        value={amount} onchange={handleAmountChange} 
        step="0.25"
        placeholder="type the number of items..." label="Enter a number"  ></lightning-input>
        <p>
            Number of Items: {amount}
        </p>
    </div>

</template>
```

Comment: This solution works great. To all who like me face the problem, that the whole number is being removed when entering a comma: This can be related to the users locale. Setting it to German (Germany) solved the issue. Having it set to German (Switzerland) seemed to cause the issue.